# Increasing the height of dayNameCells in RadCalendar

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript, nativescript-angular, nativescript-telerik-ui

I am trying to create a weekly calendar view for my nativescript application. The issue is in styling for android. The week day names do not have enough spacing at the top and bottom.

I have tried to increase the height programmatically, but it has no impact.

```
        const weekViewStyle = new CalendarWeekViewStyle();
        const dayNameCellStyle = new CellStyle();
        dayNameCellStyle.cellAlignment = CalendarCellAlignment.HorizontalCenter;
        dayNameCellStyle.cellTextSize = 14;
        dayNameCellStyle.effectiveHeight = 30;
        dayNameCellStyle.effectiveMarginBottom = 20;
        weekViewStyle.dayNameCellStyle = dayNameCellStyle;
```

[here's the link to the playground](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=ROCJgL&v=3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think the option to change the height is exposed in the plugin, but you might able to do it using the native method calls in loaded event.

```
onLoaded(event) {
    const calendar = event.object;
    if (calendar.android) {
        calendar.android.setDayNamesHeight(layout.toDevicePixels(40));
    } else {
        calendar.ios.presenter.style.dayNameCellHeight = 40;
    }
}
```

[Updated Playground](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=ROCJgL&v=4)

Comment: Yes that works, Thank you. Could you please point me to the documentation on accessing the native element settings like 'setDayNamesHeight' or 'presenter.style.dayNameCellHeight'.

Comment: Docs for [iOS](https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/ios/) & [Android](https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/android/introduction).